# Global line numbers in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In Jupyter Notebook I can toggle line numbers by pressing `Shift`+`L` in command mode. However this displays line numbers that start from 1 within each cell.

Is there a way to instead  display *global* line numbers, that is, that count from 1 at the start of the first cell of the notebook to N at the bottom of the last cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know of a "native" way to do this in Jupyter.

However, this unofficial extension does it for you : 
[jupyter-linenumbers](https://github.com/leukeleu/jupyter-linenumbers)